# What changed in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

The following spec passes fine in Ruby 2.1.5 but fails in 2.2.0 and I can't tell what that's all about:

```
# job.rb

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :link, :url => true
end

# job_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

describe Job do

  describe "#create" do
    ["blah", "http://", " "].each do |bad_link|
      it {
        should_not allow_value(bad_link).for(:link)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

fail log looks like this:

```
1) Job#create should not allow link to be set to "http://"
     Failure/Error: should_not allow_value(bad_link).for(:link)
       Expected errors when link is set to "http://",
       got no errors
     # ./spec/models/job_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I find the only way to for that spec to pass with Ruby 2.2.0 is to include the [validates_url](https://github.com/perfectline/validates_url) gem in my project!!

Does anyone know this is about?

Comment: RSpec fail log, please

Comment: This `it { should_not allow_value(bad_link).for(:link) }` is a shoulda matcher from the shoulda gem. The behavior changed in later versions - did you also update the gem? Maybe try writing the spec without the shoulda matchers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solution isn't ideal, but it works.

Replace validates_url gem by [validates gem](https://github.com/kaize/validates). It has `UrlValidator` (written by me), which is well tested.

```
gem 'validates' # in Gemfile
validates :link, :url => true # you needn't to change something. Just remove validates_url from your Gemfile
```

P.S. It's a strange way - to test functionality of gem. Functionality should be tested in gem already.

P.P.S. I'm strongly recommend you to move to ruby `2.2.1` (or `2.2.2`) instead of `2.2.0`, because of `2.2.0` has a lot of bugs

Comment: I think you are confused. I was never using the `validates_url` gem but since upgrading to Ruby 2.2.2, adding that gem is the only way to fix the failing spec.

Comment: yeah but clearly this has something to do with the Ruby version!

Comment: agree with @asiniy, rails raise ArgumentError(Unknown validator: 'UrlValidator'), or maybe you write your own UrlValidator?